# React: Unable to access and test props & state during Jest/Enzyme shallow rendering

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test state manipulation of the following method in a React.js class/component:

```
// DataSection.jsx
export default class DataSection extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      initialFetch : true,
      REPORT_OPTION : 'totals',
      viewMarker : 0,
    };
  }


    updateViewMarker = (incrementSize, plusMinusOption) => {
let {viewMarker} = this.state;
console.log(this.props, `=====this.props inside updateViewMarker=====`);
const {preparedReportData} = this.props;

// safe string to math translation
if (plusMinusOption === '-') {
  this.setState({
    viewMarker : viewMarker - incrementSize
  })
} else if (plusMinusOption === '+') {
  this.setState({
    viewMarker : viewMarker + incrementSize
  })
}
```

I'm new to Enzyme and am having trouble accessing state updates. I thought the issue might be with the instance so I have included some attempts with .instance() and the errors I received.

```
// DataSection.test.jsx

// component shallow render with dud props
const mockProp = jest.fn();
const shallowDataSection = enzyme.shallow(<DataSection
  dispatchGetDonationData={ mockProp }
  rawReportData={ mockProp }
  preparedReportData={ mockProp }
  dispatchUpdatePreparedReportData={ mockProp }
/>);

test('increments by 10', () => {
    expect(shallowDataSection.instance()).toBeInstanceOf(DataSection); // passes
    expect(shallowDataSection.state().viewMarker).toEqual(0); // passes
    // expect(shallowDataSection.instance().state().viewMarker).toEqual(0); // fails

    shallowDataSection.setProps({
      preparedReportData : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    }); 
    // shallowDataSection.instance().setProps({
    //   preparedReportData : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    // }); // setProps is not a function


    expect(shallowDataSection.props().preparedReportData.length).toEqual(12); // can't read property 'length' of undefined
    // expect(shallowDataSection.instance().props().preparedReportData.length).toEqual(12); // shallowDataSection.instance(...).props is not a function

  });
```

What is the mistake being made? The code below is my actual test but I struggle to get the prerequisites above working

```
// dataSection.instance().updateViewMarker(10, '+');
// expect(shallowDataSection.state().viewMarker).toEqual(20);
```

EDIT: libraries used:

```
"enzyme": "^3.8.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.1",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
"react": "^16.7.0",
```

Imports into DataSection.test.js:

```
const React = require("react"); 
const App = require("../App");
const DataSection = require("../components/DataSection").default;
const dataSection = new DataSection();
const enzyme = require("enzyme");
const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

enzyme.configure({ adapter : new Adapter() });
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem like you set the update the state after the incrementation.
The reason the test to assert that state is 0 passes because its undefined when you initially render the component?

Comment: you are right, I've updated it. I still get the same error: `TypeError: shallowDataSection.instance(...).props is not a function`

Comment: Have you tried using `mount(...)` instead of `shallow(...)` from enzyme? This will allow to use .setProps({...}), and .setState({...});

Comment: Mount is needed for state/props access? I will try it now

Comment: Found this [question](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1939) on github, which explains what shallow-does.